# XForms: xxforms:variable breaks xforms-alert functionality

Tags: xforms

I have the following tag in my form to capture a query string parameter.

```
<xxforms:variable name="param1" select="xxforms:get-request-parameter('param1')"/>
```

I have many form fields on this form and some of them are required fields displaying the red alert icon. As user fills these fields, the red alert icon changes to green check mark. This works fine on the form without the above variable declaration.

Adding the above line of variable declaration prevents the red alert icons from changing to green check marks when form fields are filled. Need help to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, this is because you can only use `xxforms:get-request-parameter()` when the page is being loaded, i.e. on `xforms-model-construct-done` or `xforms-ready`. So if you need the value of a request parameter later on, you need to store it in a node of an instance on `xforms-model-construct-done`, and then change your variable to point to that node (or change the code using the variable to point to the node directly).